Numbering stitches in `knitting` `\charts`
I recently discovered the quite wonderful package knitting.
It is perfect for drawing knitting patterns, as long as one has a multi line courser in ones editor of choice, it is extremely simple to work with.
I have discovered one challenge though.
When setting up a new knitting project, I like to set up a visual representation of the full pattern.
Often this requires some repeated sections. This is supported in knittingvia markers such as |, \overline, and \underline.
However, to know where to put my stitchmarkers, I would also like to know how many stitches there are for any specific pattern.
This is also supported in knitting by the \numberrow command.
However, I'm having some trouble combining repeats and \numberrow.
Below I have an MWE knitting pattern: Some moss knit with a cable in the middle.
\documentclass[multi=true]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{knitting}
\standaloneenv{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
\knitmixed

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {\chart[right]{
==--------==
==--------==
==--------==
==--------==
==kkkkKKKK==
==--------==
==--------==
==--------==
}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {\chart[right]{
--==
--==
==--
==--
}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {\chart[right]{
|--==| ==--------== |--==|
|--==| ==--------== |--==|
|==--| ==--------== |==--|
|==--| ==--------== |==--|
|--==| ==kkkkKKKK== |--==|
|--==| ==--------== |--==|
|==--| ==--------== |==--|
|==--| ==--------== |==--|
\numberrow{94}{4}{91}\numberrow{52}{12}{41}\numberrow{40}{4}{37}
}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The pattern has the two subpatterns (cable and moss knit)
The moss sections are then marked as repeats.
However, I don't know how to take repeating into account for the moss section? You can see my attempt here.
In this MWE I wanted 10 repeats of both moss sections.
So ideally I would like the numbers:

1 under the rightmost column
41 under the first column outside the first repeat
53 under the first column in the second moss stitch
92 under the leftmost column

And optionally:

40 under leftmost stitch in first moss section
52 under the last column in the cable section

But I have no idea how to get this numbering.
I looked over the knitting documentation but custom numbering seems mainly to bee for rows (such as numbering individual rows).
My attempt in the above MWE also seems to misalign numbers between columns, so ideally the stitch numbers should stay aligned with their columns.
Thanks for any and all help.
The MWE above produces:

